# Desaturate Images with Javascript/jQuery/CSS IN CHROME

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, grayscale

I can't seem to find a way to render grayscale images from colored images **in Chrome** with CSS or Javascript. I have a feeling that any Canvas solution won't work in Chrome and was looking for another.

Any help is appreciated, I've tried Pixastic and a bunch of other jQuery solutions, all to no avail.

Comment: "I have a feeling that any Canvas solution won't work in Chrome and was looking for another" - **why?** "I've tried Pixastic and a bunch of other jQuery solutions" - **what goes wrong?** [Pixastic works fine in Chrome..](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/desaturate/)

Comment: I have tried a lot of alternatives to this and found none that is sustainable. The final resort - the usual one... gray-scale attached to color and background switching via CSS.

Comment: @thirtydot if you look at the bottom of that page you sent ( [link](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/desaturate/) ) you'll notice that Chrome is not one of the supported browsers

Comment: @Joseph Szymborski: Yeah, but "WebKit nightly" is, and that page was written a while ago. What was then a "WebKit nightly" is now an old version of Chrome/Safari (which are WebKit-based browsers). Pixastic uses a canvas in exactly the same way that your accepted answer does..

Comment: @thirtydot Yup, I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted to do a similar thing a week or two ago and found this example:

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/html5-grayscale-image-hover

It works by rendering the image to canvas, grayscaling it and then getting the Base64 representation.  It's not for IE, but since you specified Chrome, you should be good to go.

Just for the sake of completeness, grayscaling an image in IE can be done with the

```
filter: gray;
```

css option

Comment: I've seen this prior, and hasn't been working in Chromium, but works in Chrome. Guess one can't ask for things to work in browsers that are in beta. Thanks!

Comment: I'm currently running Chromium under Ubuntu and it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

This may help:

```
    filter: grayscale(100%);
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
-moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
-ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
-o-filter: grayscale(100%);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Javascript is a requirement for you, or if you plan to use this on dynamic images, but I put together a tutorial that explains how to do this using only CSS/HTML. It makes use of the `opacity` and `transition` style declarations. With this, two images can create a "transition illusion" between themselves using the `:hover` pseudo-selector.

Check it out and let me know if it helps at all. http://www.stephenwalcher.com/blog/2012/01/22/javascript-free-image-desaturat/